# I got an error reading a character on C

Tags: c

I want to read a single character from the console, but when I do, the program reads characters yet and I must write another character to save the first and finish its execution.

Code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char peps;
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("write a character:\n");
    scanf(" %c\n", &peps);
    printf("%c\n", peps);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why it does that and how to correct this error?

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: I write a character to the program and the program doesn't save until read another one. I.e. I write "j" and press "enter ", but the program is waiting for a character yet even though I wrote "j".

Comment: Remove the `\n` in `scanf()`

Comment: It works now! haha, i didn't saw the error until you told. Thanks :D

Comment: @EmmanCanVaz_95 Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859277/behaviour-of-scanf-when-newline-is-in-the-format-string) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `\n` from the `scanf()`, it should work as you want.

ie, do

```
scanf(" %c", &peps);
```

instead of

```
scanf(" %c\n", &peps);
```

This is because the `\n` in the `scanf()` format string is telling the computer to read and ignore all white spaces (including `\n`) after reading a character.

So all white spaces including the newlines given by typing the enter key, would be ignored. This will stop only when a non-white space character is encountered which won't be read and would thus remain in the input buffer.

So, in your case, a character would first be read and it would wait for a non-white space character before executing the `printf()` following the `scanf()`. The non-white space character would remain in the input buffer and was not read and is hence not printed at once. It would be read only upon reading from the `stdin` again.

If you want to explore this further, consider placing that `scanf()` and `printf()` in a loop and examine the output.

Note that replacing that `\n` with a space  would have the same effect.

ie,

```
scanf(" %c\n", &peps);
```

and

```
scanf(" %c ", &peps);
```

would have the same behavior.

[What's the behavior of scanf when the format string ends with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269208/whats-the-behavior-of-scanf-when-the-format-string-ends-with-a-newline)

[Behaviour of scanf when newline is in the format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859277/behaviour-of-scanf-when-newline-is-in-the-format-string)

Comment: Wow! That's a great and usefull answer! thank you by far to help me with my little problem :D.