# how to use scanf correctly

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, scanf

scanf asks for 2 values ​​for the first time
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olll7.png)
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS Does not help
I don't understand how to make scanf read only the first number
please help solve the problem

```
void menu() {
    int n = 0;
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    printf("1-input\n2-dobstr\n3-del\n4-check\n5-save\n6-upload\n7-vyvod\n8-sort\n9-exit\n");
    while (n != 9) {
        printf("what do you want to choose\n");
        scanf("%d\n", &n);
        switch (n != 9) {
        case 1:
            //vvod();
            break;
        case 2:
            //dobstr();
            break;
        case 3:
            //del();
            break;
        case 4:
            //check();
            break;
        case 5:
            //save();
            break;
        case 6:
            //upload();
            break;
        case 7:
            //vyvod();
            break;
        case 8:
            //sort();
            break;
        }
    }
}



int main(){
    menu();
}
```

Comment: Remove the newline from your format string. [What's the behavior of scanf when the format string ends with a newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269208/whats-the-behavior-of-scanf-when-the-format-string-ends-with-a-newline)

Comment: Tip: Do not use `scanf();`.  Use `fgets()` to read a line of user input into a string, then parse the string.